# ObjectListView (TreeListView) change the background color

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview, treelistview

I am using a TreeListView (ObjectListView - http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) and populated it with a number of items. How can I change the background color in the column where the hierarchy? For the second and further columns (subitems) I use this.olvColumn.Renderer = new <...> and override the method Render (CheckStateRender, BaseRender etc). I tried TreeListViev.TreeRender, but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the background of the cell, listen for the `CellFormat` event.

If you want to do something fancier, created a subclass of `TreeRenderer` and then assign an instance of your subclass to the `TreeColumnRenderer` property of your `TreeListView`.